# Set a custom icon for gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

Is it possible to set a custom icon for `gnome-terminal`, maybe dependent on the profile. I often have many terminal windows open and it gets a bit tricky to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The icon for gnome-terminal is set at the C level and does not provide for any customization. You will need to use [xseticon](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/xseticon/) to change it externally.

Answer (score 1):

This was possible in the past. But Gnome developers it was a bug to allow this as the main theme should define the icon, not the terminal profile. See https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=126081